# Laravel blade can't print double curly brackets

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I want to print double curly brackets from a Laravel blade template. Here is what I've tried so far and failed:

```
@{{ n }}

{!! '&#123;&#123; n &#125;&#125;' }}

@php echo '{{ n }}'; @endphp

@php echo '&#123;&#123; n &#125;&#125;'; @endphp
```

Here is the view I have:

```
<div class="new-page">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <h3 class="col-md-6 center">Page @if(isset($n)) {{ $n }} @else @{{ n }} @endif</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Weirdly, when I try any of the above there is no error it just displays an empty page.

I am using Laravel 5.6, I've also tried googling but no solution worked.

It turns out the default app.js file that comes with Laravel is throwing an error and it is breaking the page - I don't know exactly why though. The error is as follows:

```
n is not defined
```

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-escape-double-curly-braces-in-a-blade-template

Comment: @AbdEllatifLakehal I saw that one, solution doesn't work.

Comment: @Script47 Saw that one too, it also doesn't work.

Comment: Is error reporting on? Also are short tags on as well? Also look at the **source** of the page, not just what the browser renders.

Comment: The syntax you are using is correct. It's probably something related to the version of php and/or some settings.

Comment: @IvankaTodorova very weird when you right click on the page and inspect an element you can see the body has just an empty comment in it, but when you click 'View page source' it displays the HTML correctly including the curly brackets - no idea what's going on

Comment: would you like to show us the full page?

Comment: @PetarVasilev then your HTML is probably invalid. You have missed to close a div (or other element) and that breaks the page.

Comment: @IvankaTodorova something in the default app.js file that comes with Laravel is breaking the page, the error is: n is not defined. I guess something in app.js is trying to parse the page.

Answer (score 0):

`Page <?php if(isset($n)) echo "{{ ".$n." }}"; else echo "{{ ".n." }}"; ?>`

This will work quite fine you can check below screenshots

[image: Code]

[image: Image Results]

Answer (score 0):

Try once using php tag like

```
<?php if(isset($n)) echo $n;  else echo "{{ n }}"; ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you not do something like:

```
@php echo "{{" . {{ $n }} . "}}" @endphp
```

The question being is n a variable passed in or created by a controller or declared earlier in the view?

Comment: This would produce a syntax error.

Comment: Is n a variable passed in from a controller or created earlier in the blade template?